# Proper format for custom ListActivity layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout, listactivity

I'm trying to add a header to the top of a ListView that is declared in a ListActivity and I am trying to use the method where one includes the ListView inside a LinearLayout and id's the listview as @android:id/list.

I am receiving a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

after my setContentView() call in the activity.  I can't seem to find the problem and I assume it is with formatting or something, can someone help me out?

Here is the xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="0dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"/>

<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="224dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toprighttext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomrighttext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by having separate header.xml in your layout,add the first three lines of code in your oncreate method in your activity,like below

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);          
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
        R.layout.brupress_header);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brupress_header_text);
        tv.setText("Header");
        setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Do I still call setContentView or do I used .getListView() since I am extending a ListActivity?